# Horizontal scroll action for submenus

Tags: html, css, wordpress, horizontal-scrolling, submenu

I want to create a horizontal scroll menu for my website in mobile view. I got CSS code from somewhere and it worked but it worked only for menus. So, I want CSS code for submenus as well. How can I do that?

CSS code that worked for the horizontal scroll menu is listed below :

```
selector ul{ /* let's set the horizontal layout for our menu */
     white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto; 
    overflow-y: hidden;
    flex-wrap: inherit !important;
    scrollbar-width: none; /* this will remove scroll-bar for mozilla based browser */
}

selector a{ /* some graphic adjustmend for the A tag */
    background: #161C2E;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

selector ul::-webkit-scrollbar { /* now, let's remove the scroll-bar from the menu */
  display: none; }
```

Comment: Please share your HTML also

Comment: I didn't use HTML. I directly used this CSS code on Elementor custom CSS of that particular section on WordPress.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We mean the menu / submenu HTML on your website that the CSS get's applied to. CSS on it's own does nothing, so we need to see see the HTML that it has to work with.

Comment: I have no knowledge in coding and I'm sorry but don't know how to get the HTML code of my menu and sub-menu section because I managed to find the video of the horizontal scroll menu on YouTube and directly got the CSS code which was provided in the video itself and pasted that code in the custom CSS section of elementor page builder on WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

As a sub-menu in wordpress is normally a `ul` inside of another `ul`, you can target these elements as well:

```
selector ul, selector ul ul { 
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto; 
    overflow-y: hidden;
    flex-wrap: inherit !important;
    scrollbar-width: none;
}
```

Comment: Should I modify it or use it directly in my CSS code section ? Because I tried this code in elementor custom CSS of that particular section and it didn't work.

Comment: Please use the inspector of your browser (right click and "inspect element" or similar) to see the html code of your menu. With this we can help you some more